# Try to prevent reload page when hit enter in input type text in old version of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Need your help friends

I made a functions o prevent reload page when hit enter in input type text in old version of Internet Explorer. it is working in new version of Internet Explorer but in the old version (Below 8) This code doesnt work. I use this browser to programm this because i this page will be displayed in a barcode scanner machine (a portable console) which is old version of internet explorer browser was installed.

here's the code HTML and Javascript :

```
<td align='left'><input type='text' size='15' name='packing_to_id' id='packing_to_id' size='10' value='' onkeypress="return InputKeyPress(event)"></td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function InputKeyPress(e){

  e=e||window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode;
  if(key==13) 
  {

     return false; 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my machine. I have created a sample with your code, after entering values into the text box and click the Enter button, it sill not refresh the page (reload the page). Please check your code, whether there have any other code which will reload the page, such as text box change event?

Comment: Are you using old version of Internet Explorer that error can be reproduce using old Internet Explorer ? But the problem solved already I put <form onsubmit="return false;"> and it work

Comment: yes, I also test it using the old version of Internet Explorer. Glad to hear you have solved this problem, congratulation.

Answer (score 0):

Use event.returnValue = false;

Sample Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function InputKeyPress(e){

  e=e||window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode;
  if(key==13) 
  {
     e.returnValue = false;
     return false; 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Still doesnt work. Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: still doesnt work still reloading page dont know why

Comment: this is working for me i add this in element form:

<form onsubmit="return false;">